# Abhinava Gupta's bhashyam for Srimad Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, abhinavagupta

Does any one know if there really is a Bhashyam for Srimad Bhagavad Gita by Sri Abhinava Gupta? If yes, how can I get a copy? Is it available in print? or is there an online copy?

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Yes it is there and you can read it at this website - https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/

Comment: Thank you @Lazy Lubber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the Gitartha Sangraha, Acharya Abhinavagupta's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita, online in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ayco.it/files/963/Yoga/0BwEwR7MZZMxITjhvU2JoS1hNeVk/ABHINAVAGUPTA%2520-Bhagavad-Gita-Commentary-by-AbhinavaGupta.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiTzY7QoofmAhVmyjgGHQqqD-QQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw280KhI_9OYg23HSuVrYVpC).

Comment: Thank you Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury